# Exhibit a smooth quotient map from the disk $D^n$ or $\mathbb{R}^n$ to the sphere $S^n$.

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology

It is easy to find *continuous* quotient maps that glue the boundary of the disk
$D^n = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : \lVert x\rVert \le 1\}$ to one point to make $S^n = \{y \in \mathbb{R}^{n + 1} : \lVert y\rVert = 1\}$.
(The norm here is the $l^2$ norm, which is smooth at all points except the origin)
For example, we could take the map $x \mapsto \left(\frac{2\sqrt{\lVert x \rVert (1 - \lVert x\rVert)}}{\lVert x\rVert} x, 2\lVert x \rVert - 1\right)$.
This is obviously continuous where $x \not= 0$, but is also continuous at $0$ because as $x$ goes to $0$, the image goes to $(0, -1)$.
As $D^n$ is compact and $S^n$ is Hausdorff, this is a closed, and therefore, quotient map.

But this is not a smooth map since it contains the norm and square root, both of which are not smooth at $0$.

Is there a nice modification that gives a smooth quotient map?
What about quotient maps from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $S^n$?

Comment: There are no quotient map $\Bbb R^n \to S^n$ as a continuous image of a compact is compact.

Comment: The same map extended to all of $\mathbb{R}^n$ by mapping each point outside $D^n$ to $(0, 1)$ is a quotient map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $S^n$.
$\mathbb{R}^n$ is not a compact space.

Comment: sorry you are right, my comment didn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea of using stereographic projection (as indicated by the map you've provided) is a good one; we can fix things up by looking at a slight modification.

As you note, the norm map $x\mapsto \|x\|$ is not smooth at $0\in\mathbb{R}^n$.  The *square* of this map, however, is smooth.  Thus we can define a map $f\colon D^n\setminus\partial D^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ by
\begin{equation}
f(x) = \dfrac{x}{1-\|x\|^2},
\end{equation}
and this map will be smooth.  We then have a stereographic projection map $g\colon \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ given by
\begin{equation}
g(x) = \left(\dfrac{2x}{\|x\|^2+1},\dfrac{\|x\|^2-1}{\|x\|^2+1}\right),
\end{equation}
and this map is also smooth.  The composition $g\circ f$ then gives us a map from $D^n\setminus\partial D^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.  Do you see how we could extend this composition to a map defined on all of $D^n$?  Moreover, can you conclude that this gives a surjection $D^n\to S^n$, and that it plays nicely with the relevant topologies?

Comment: Okay, so just composing gives me a formula $x \mapsto \left(\frac{2(1 - \lVert x \rVert^2)}{(\lVert x\rVert^2 + 1)^2} x, \frac{- \lVert x \rVert^4 + 6 \lVert x \rVert^2 - 1}{(\lVert x\rVert^2 + 1)^2}\right)$ which defines a smooth quotient map from $D^n$ to $S^n$.
But this does not extend to a smooth quotient map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $S^n$. The $1 - \lVert x\rVert^2$ term needs to be abruptly changed to simply $0$ as you pass the boundary of the disk, and now you lose smoothness.